# How to verify if AoT is working or not [ Webpack 2 , Angular 2 ]?

Tags: angular, webpack

In my sample Angular 2 SPA , I have used Webpack 2 in order to

1. Bundle all my js files
2. Implement "Tree Shaking" to remove dead code and reduce bundle js file size
3. and to implement Ahead-of-time compilation to reduce the bundle js file size further.

I was able to achive "1" and "2" by creating a webpack.config.js file , and below are the contents of this file

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/main.js',       
    plugins: [

    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        compress: false
    })
    ],
    output: {
        filename:'./src/bundle.js'
    }
}
```

"webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin" plugin which does the Tree Shaking and minfication , reduced my bundle.js file size from 3 mb to 1 mb.

Next in order to implement AoT compilation , I have used [@ngtools/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) , and below is the 
modified webpack.config.js file with AoT related code.

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/main.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [

    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        compress: false
    }),
     new AotPlugin({         
          tsConfigPath: 'src\\tsconfig.json',
          mainPath: 'main.ts',         
          "skipCodeGeneration": true
      }), 
    ],
    output: {
        filename:'./src/bundle.js'
    }
}
```

After AoT the size of bundle.js file is still same(1 mb).

Now my question is how can I check/know whether AoT compilation is working or not ?

Comment: None of the answers explain what mistake I have done if there is any in the 3 steps mentioned , or what needs to be modified ...

Answer (score 18):

The best way to make sure that your Angular project is built using `AOT` is to get your hands dirty and take a look into the compiled source code.

**What does AOT really do behind the scenes?**
`AOT` is compiling your `HTML` into `JS` functions which can be statically analysed (and later tree shaked).

So just take a part of your `HTML` template and look for it inside your compiled JS. For example, here's my `login.component.html` in one of my projects:

```html
<md-card>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)" fxLayout="column">
    <md-input-container class="margin-top-x1">
      <span mdPrefix>
          <md-icon color="primary">person</md-icon>
        </span>
      <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" required>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="margin-top-x1">
      <span mdPrefix>
          <md-icon color="primary">vpn_key</md-icon>
        </span>
      <input mdInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required>
    </md-input-container>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100%" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="form-error" *ngIf="users.connectionFailed">
      <md-icon color="warn">error</md-icon>
      <p>Username and password do not match</p>
    </div>

    <button md-raised-button color="primary" class="margin-top-x1" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid || users.isConnecting || users.isConnected">
      <span *ngIf="!users.isConnecting && !users.isConnected">
        Log in
      </span>

      <span *ngIf="users.isConnecting || users.isConnected" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        Logging in <md-spinner></md-spinner>
      </span>
    </button>
  </form>
</md-card>
```

Grab something easy to search, that will probably have few occurrences. For example here, the md-icon `vpn_key`. When I search in dist folder once built with AOT, I can find that my view has been compiled to:

[image]

And how would it be **without AOT**?

Like that: 
[image]

**We can see that the whole template hasn't been compiled into JS without AOT !**

**Potential problem with your build system**
When you say:

> 1) Bundle all my js files
>   2) Implement "Tree Shaking" to remove dead code and reduce bundle js file size
>   3) and to implement Ahead-of-time compilation to reduce the bundle js file size further.

If you bundle and implement Tree Shaking **before** the AOT compilation it won't work of course.

***OFF TOPIC:***
Bundle size seems to mater for you and if you're not already using Angular v4 I'd advise you to give a try. Few/no breaking changes yet (4.0.0-rc.2 as I'm writing) and the template compiler has been rewritten. It now generate less code for the views (~40 to ~50% less than Angular v2.x)

Comment: Somehow confusing: Angular 2 vs. Angular v4. But I found a blogpost that [explains](http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html) it quite well.

Comment: @JanHommes Angular v4.x won't probably break your code ;) Just make it smaller at compilation :)

Comment: yes, that one I understand from your post. But I did not know that there is already a v4. But its due the fact they changed to semantic versioning. Also my understanding is that v2.4.3 is the same as v4.0.0-beta3.

Answer (score 4):

After AOT compilation, treeshaking should remove @angular/compiler (which is respectively used during JIT. And if u do simple size analysis you will learn that almost 40% of Angular 2 is Compiler so sazie

Answer (score 4):

You can use [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) to view the content of your main.bundle.js and you can compare the AOT bundle with the non-AOT bundle. Hope it helps.

Comment: I use source-map-explorer and also webpack-bundle-analyzer, the latter is able to show multiple bundles at the same time.