# Angular 4 to 5 upgrade - angular5 + webpack3 + aot + ngc - missing ngfactory

Tags: webpack, aot, angular5

Looks like genDir has been deprecated in Angular 5 so i removed genDir and only have outDir

It fails when it comes to bootstrapping the modules as it can't find app.module.ngfactory.

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../built/app.module.ngfactory';
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

---

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false, 
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": false,
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
        "jquery",
        "jasmine"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2015",
        "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": { 
        "*" : ["*", "node_modules/*"]
    },       
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "./built"
}
```

I can't seem to figure out where this file is generated now

Comment: Then answer here helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365240/angular-5-webpack-3-aot?rq=1